# Disable IE prompt for download

Tags: internet-explorer

This issue has driven me crazy for a week already. Unfortunately I still cannot find a proper solution.

Here is the scenario, I need to download then automatically open an **MSG** outlook mail file from my asp system by IE without prompt for "Open" or "Save as".
So far I have tried various methods but none works:

I have followed this instruction by editing the registry (http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/). However, this seems to work only for a static link like (http: //example.com/Filename.msg). It does not work for my case which is a dynamic link like (http://example.com/index.aspx?Page=DOWNLOAD?asbdasd?File=Filename.msg)

I am using Internet Explorer 11 on a Windows 7 64bit.
Hope someone can help me to figure out this issue.